How to capture values of cypher and context from GraphCypherQAChain while it is running in a loop
I am using opensource LLama3 without OpenAI or Groq and need to use GraphCypherQAChain to get the cypher and context and use it to generate an answer. But I am unable to capture the values while it is running. I want to recursively run the chain until I have values for both cypher and Full context.
I am thinking here to store the logs in a file and then parse it to get cypher and context. Fyi, I am running this on Sagemaker Jupyter notebook instance. Need suggestions
Relevant code:
CYPHER_GENERATION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["schema", "question"], template=CYPHER_GENERATION_TEMPLATE
)

# Function to extract Cypher from logs
def extract_cypher_from_logs(logs):
    pattern = r"Generated Cypher:(.*?)Full Context:"
    match = re.search(pattern, logs, re.DOTALL)
    if match:
        return match.group(1).strip()
    return None

# Function to extract context from logs
def extract_context_from_logs(logs):
    pattern = r"Full Context:(.*)"
    match = re.search(pattern, logs, re.DOTALL)
    if match:
        context_str = match.group(1).strip()
        try:
            context = eval(context_str)  # Safely evaluate the context list from string
            return context
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error extracting context: {e}")
    return None

# Function to run chain and collect valid cypher and context
def generate_valid_cypher_and_context(chain, question, max_iterations=10):
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        try:
            result = chain.invoke(question)['result']
            logs = sys.stdout.getvalue()
            sys.stdout.flush()  # Flush stdout to ensure prints are visible immediately
            
            cypher = extract_cypher_from_logs(logs)
            context = extract_context_from_logs(logs)
            
            if cypher and context:
                return cypher, context
            
            # Reduce or eliminate sleep time based on performance needs
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Adjust sleep time as needed
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error invoking chain: {e}")
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Adjust sleep time as needed
    
    return None, None

# Example usage
schema = graph.schema  # Replace with your actual schema object
chain = GraphCypherQAChain.from_llm(graph=graph, llm=llm, cypher_prompt=CYPHER_GENERATION_PROMPT, verbose=True, validate_cypher=True)

questions = "What Departments are present in the Org. Dav?"
valid_cypher, valid_context = generate_valid_cypher_and_context(chain, questions)

if valid_cypher and valid_context:
    print("Valid Cypher Query:")
    print(valid_cypher)
    print("\nValid Context:")
    print(valid_context)
else:
    print("No valid Cypher query and context found within the specified iterations.")

